# Learn MVC3 with or without DI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection

I want to learn MVC3 by creating my own website.

The book MVC3 Pro by Apress is good, but also introduces Dependency Injection, which makes it a bit complicated in the beginning.

What is recommended?

1) Learning DI first before continuing or should I skip DI for now until I have learned MVC. 
2) If I skip DI now, how complicated is it to rewrite my code to use DI?

Comment: DI is not a complicated approach once you get used to it. There good libraries out there which integrates with ASP.NET MVC 3 (Ninject [as explain it the book that you are reading], StructureMap). I'd suggest you to go for DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use Dependency Injection, its really not *that* hard

Here is a [good blog post that explains pretty well how to do DI in mvc3](http://kenneththorman.blogspot.com/2011/03/aspnet-mvc-3-dependency-injection-using.html). You could pretty much just copypaste everything and have DI using castle-windsor (which is also covered by the book).

If you skip DI now, how complicated it will be to rewrite it with DI depends on your code quality. If you write you code still using [Inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) then adding DI will be pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think you should follow what the book is teaching. I'd spend the time to learn, or ask questions on here or programmer in order to better understand DI.

It's such a worthwhile pattern, the benefits outweigh the time spent understanding.